# Can’t go to a particular question: too many redirections

Tags: bug, status-completed

Whenever I try to visit the question [Quand « de » et quand « du » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/quand%2D%C2%AB%25C2%25A0du%25C2%25A0%C2%BB%2Det%2Dquand%2D%C2%AB%25C2%25A0), my browser fails and claims that there were too many redirections. I have seen the same behaviour recently, but don’t remember if it was with the same or a different question.

Comment: Same problem here (Firefox 33 nightly/Kubuntu 14.04)

Comment: It's an SE bug, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/redirect-loop-after-editing-a-question-title-ending-with-no-break-space-questio

Comment: Meanwhile you can access it with the "date" link on the right.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for the bug is now in place.

You can track further evolution and see technical explanations on [the bug report on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/redirect-loop-after-editing-a-question-title-ending-with-no-break-space-questio/233868#233868).